# With woocommerce_order_get_items filter hook manipulate items name

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

In WooCommerce, I have tried to figure out how to remove the `()` if the order lines items names have those parenthesis.

Here is some code:

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id)
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $order_item ){
   //...enter code here
}
```

But i want to use filter hooks, since I can't access the `foreach` loop above. I tried to add to `functions.php` so when get_items() calls, the filter will prepare the data array.

Here is that code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_items', 'filter_woocommerce_order_get_items', 10, 2 ); 
function filter_woocommerce_order_get_items($items, $instance){
    foreach ($items as $item){
        $search = array('å','ä','ö','(', ')');
        $replace = array('a','a','o', '', '');
        $item['name'] = str_replace($search, $replace, $item['name']);
    }

    return $items;
}
```

So, TL;DR:
Can I prepare data when `$order->get_items()` calls?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right direction using the correct filter hook, but actually your custom hooked function doesn't work as something is missing.

To make it work you need to replace the old values by the new ones in the **`$items`** array, before returning it. So the missing element in your code is the **`$item_id`** **key**.

I have make some little changes in your code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_items', 'filter_woocommerce_order_get_items', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_order_get_items($items, $instance){
    foreach ($items as $item_id => $item_values){

        $search = array('å','ä','ö','(', ')');
        $replace = array('a','a','o', '', '');

        $items[$item_id]['name'] = str_replace($search, $replace, $item_values['name']);
    }
    return $items;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and works.

Comment: Hello yeah i missed out that part. I was checking on /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php line 1229 but didnt notice  $items[ $item->order_item_id ]['name']  . Thanks!